# Workaround for automatic replacement of "\r" to "\n"

Tags: notebooks, options, character-encoding

When I run the following code in an empty notebook

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], testOption -> "\n\r"]
```

and then open the notebook in Notepad, I find

> $CellContext`testOption -> "\n\n"

(1) Can you confirm this bug/feature in other versions/operative systems? I am using Mathematica 9.0.1 in Win8Prox64.

(2) Is there a workaround?

Comment: I have tested it in Win7x64, Mathematica 9.0.1 and this is set, as desired, to \n\r

Comment: `\n` is newline and `\r` is carriage return. It's OS specific because running your line and saving and reading into TextEdit on Mac OS gives `$CellContext`testOption -> "\n\n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the same behavior in Win7Prox64/Mathematica 9.0.1.

I may be missing something but AFAIK adding arbitrary new options to a notebook object isn't a documented/supported feature. So you'd have to accept whatever this does and also if it wouldn't work at all. The only useful purpose of such an unkown option that I can think of is to store extra information in the notebook object and the corresponding notebook expression. For that there is the documented and supported `TaggingRules` option which lets you store extra rules to notebook objects. Using `TaggingRules` receiving the information is also supported and working using the two argument version of `Options` and `CurrentValue` (which both won't work with an unknown option). So you might want consider using `TaggingRules` instead of introducing a new option.

As for the conversion of the string: If you get back the string in the same session with `testOption /. Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]`, the `\r` will remain, only when it is written to file it is converted to `\n`. When reopening the notebook from file, one will also get the converted `\n` with `Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]`. Maybe that can explain why not everybody reports the same behavior even on similar systems, but it could also be some setting or a sideeffect of a setting. It might be worth noting that the exact same thing does also happen when you use `TaggingRules`.

One thing that comes to mind as a workaround is to `Compress` before setting and `Uncompress` before reading (shown here with `CurrentValue` and `TaggingRules`):

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "TestOption"}] = Compress["\n\r"]

CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "TestOption"}] // Uncompress // InputForm
```

the resulting string shouldn't contain any special characters that would be touched when writing to file. Of course the resulting file content isn't human readable, so whether that is a useful workaround for your problem depends on what you try to achieve. You might want to explain that in more detail for better suggestions...

Comment: The (made up) option was for the purposes of a minimal working example. The main problem is that the string is part of a button that is docked. The `Uncompress` trick will do.